# Replace category names with ids saving hierarchy

Tags: mysql

I have such `data` table:

```
category_name | subcategory_name | other data
---------------------------------------------
fruits        | apples           | ...
fruits        | oragnes          | ...
```

What is the best way to replace category and subcategory names with its ids, moving them to other table? Getting this in result:

`category` table:

```
id | name   | parent_id
------------------------
1  | fruits | 0
2  | apples | 1
3  | oragnes| 1
```

`data` table:

```
category_id | subcategory_id | other data
---------------------------------------------
1           | 2              | ...
1           | 3              | ...
```

I can do all manually using some select distinct and join queries , but is there any better way?

Answer (score 0):

There likely is an easier way to do this; but mysql doesn't contain many of the window functions I'd like to user here, nor common table expressions, nor views with user variables.... So I'm left with a bit of a mess but it seems to work...

I'm assuming your current model could have N-Levels.
 I'm also assuming a subCategory doesn't exist under multiple categories..

What this does is

1. Generate a set of data which contains the "names" we had to find all the names of categories without parents and union those to the names with parents.
2. Then we assigned a user variables (@) to generate a new ID each item.  Two different variables were used so numbering didn't wrap from one query to the next.
3. We then copied that query into two separate sub queries (A,B in my example) and joined them to get the parent ids.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/38794/11/0)

```
-- distinct used to get 1 record for each parent and an outer wraper to return just desired results

Select Distinct A.ID as ID, A.SubCategory_name name, B.ID as Parent_ID  from (
  ---this select assigns a row number for each named value
  Select @rn:=@rn+1 ID, t1.*
  from (
    --Get just parents without any parent
    Select NULL as Category_Name, F1.category_name as SubCategory_name
    FROM (Select distinct category_Name from foo) F1 
    LEFT JOIN Foo F2 
      on F1.Category_name = F2.SubCategory_name
    where F2.SubCategory_name is null

    UNION ALL
    --get just children of parents
    SELECT category_name, subcategory_Name from foo) T1
    -- Used to get a row number assigned
    CROSS JOIN (SELECT @rn:=0) t2
    -- used to ensure same order applied to both queries so numbers match
    -- though now that I think about it I don't think we need numbers in 2nd query
    order by Category_name, SubCategory_Name) A

 LEFT JOIN (
  Select @r:=@r+1 ID, t1.*
  from (
    Select NULL as Category_Name, F1.category_name as SubCategory_name
    FROM (Select distinct category_Name from foo) F1 
    LEFT JOIN Foo F2 
    on F1.Category_name = F2.SubCategory_name
    where F2.SubCategory_name is null

    UNION ALL
    SELECT category_name, subcategory_Name from foo) T1
    CROSS JOIN (SELECT @r:=0) t2
   order by Category_name, SubCategory_Name) B
on B.SubCategory_Name = A.Category_name
```

and from the above select you could create table, or populate a table.